# image.onerror event persists after handling

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple function that checks the availability of an image in Javascript:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    // resource found
};
img.onerror = function() {
    // resource not found
};
img.src = "http://some.image.to/check.png";
```

When I try this for an non existant image, the code works, but the 404 still persists in the Javascript console (in chrome):

[image]

Any thoughts on an neat solution?

Comment: Show your html `head` tag.

Comment: _“Any thoughts on an neat solution?”_ - to what exact problem? You requested an image that did not exist, and you got the appropriate error message. Works as designed, why should it be any other way?

Comment: Being used to Java, I expected no error message to be displayed because I _'catched the exception'_.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behaviour of any browser to show the errors that occur on the page.
what you can really do is make a custom error function just sufficient enough to hide your error.

```
console.error = function(){}
```

Warning: This will hide all errors on the console.

Comment: Yeah because the browser console shows the error of a 404 image and you cannot override it.. So this is the solution i would recommend if Nero Vanbiervliet is concerned about the errors in console.

Comment: Are you serious? Fix your code instead supressing errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I won't use this solution as this might cause other errors to be undetected. I'll try to use a different method to check the availability of an image, without using the Image class.